# Newbie question - what's the easiest way to calculate the distance between points in a csv file?

Tags: csv, location, maps, distance, spreadsheet

Please go easy on me - I'm a bit of a newbie.

I have >2500 location-based entries in a csv file. Location is provided in easting/northing format, as well as UK postcode.

I need to calculate the distance between all of these with one fixed point (that can also be provided in easting/northing or UK postcode). Driving distance would be ideal, but something more simple (e.g. as the crow flies) would be fine.

I tried using Google scripts on Sheets, but I very quickly hit the usage limit.

Is there a relatively easy coding-based solution to this? I don't have a lot of experience, but I'm ready and willing to follow instructions/YouTube tutorials to get this done.

Any advice would be **massively** appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need scripts for this. In your spreadsheet, add a column that calculates the distance. You can enter your fixed coordinates in two separate cells (one each for X and Y). Then, in your distance column, you can create a constant reference to these cells to calculate the distance from this coordinate (using the Pythagorean theorem).

See image below for an example:

[image]

Formula used (for row 2):

```
=SQRT(POWER(B2-$H$1, 2) + POWER(C2-$H$2, 2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is absolutely perfect. I assume the result just needs to be divided by 1000 for km?

Comment: @hexis that would depend on what unit your coordinates are in. If each unit of X or Y represents a meter, then yes you can divide the final result of the formula by 1000 to convert to km.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you! :)